# How to return a colour from a string using UIColour Extension swift

Tags: swift

I want to be able to change a `String` ("r,g,b,a") to a `UIColor`, using `UIColor extension`. I have found this code from other answers. I am just not sure how to 'return' `returnColour` using the extension. I'm probably doing this in completely the wrong way, would like some guidance, thank in advance!

```
convenience init(fromString: String) {
    self.init()
    let scanner = Scanner(string: fromString)
    let skipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[], ")
    let comma = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ",")
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = skipped

    var r, g, b, a : NSString?

    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &r)
    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &g)
    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &b)
    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &a)

    guard let rUnwrapped = r else { return }
    guard let gUnwrapped = g else { return }
    guard let bUnwrapped = b else { return }
    guard let aUnwrapped = a else { return }

    let rfloat = CGFloat(rUnwrapped.doubleValue)
    let gfloat = CGFloat(gUnwrapped.doubleValue)
    let bfloat = CGFloat(bUnwrapped.doubleValue)
    let afloat = CGFloat(aUnwrapped.doubleValue)

    let returnColour = UIColor(red: rfloat, green: gfloat, blue: bfloat, alpha: afloat)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let colourString = "68,68,68,1.0"
let thisColour: UIColor = .init(fromString: colourString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a `convenience init` in extension you must to call `self.init` with your new params.

**Try this example:**

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(fromString: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: fromString)
        let skipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[], ")
        let comma = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ",")
        scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = skipped

        var r, g, b, a : NSString?

        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &r)
        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &g)
        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &b)
        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &a)

        guard let rUnwrapped = r else { fatalError() }
        guard let gUnwrapped = g else { fatalError() }
        guard let bUnwrapped = b else { fatalError() }
        guard let aUnwrapped = a else { fatalError() }

        let rfloat = CGFloat(rUnwrapped.doubleValue)
        let gfloat = CGFloat(gUnwrapped.doubleValue)
        let bfloat = CGFloat(bUnwrapped.doubleValue)
        let afloat = CGFloat(aUnwrapped.doubleValue)

        self.init(red: rfloat, green: gfloat, blue: bfloat, alpha: afloat)
    }
}
```

Also you can set the init as optional and return nil when the guard's fails.

**Example:**

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(fromString: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: fromString)
        let skipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[], ")
        let comma = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ",")
        scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = skipped

        var r, g, b, a : NSString?

        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &r)
        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &g)
        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &b)
        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: comma, into: &a)

        guard let rUnwrapped = r, let gUnwrapped = g, let bUnwrapped = b, let aUnwrapped = a else { return nil }

        let rfloat = CGFloat(rUnwrapped.doubleValue)
        let gfloat = CGFloat(gUnwrapped.doubleValue)
        let bfloat = CGFloat(bUnwrapped.doubleValue)
        let afloat = CGFloat(aUnwrapped.doubleValue)

        self.init(red: rfloat, green: gfloat, blue: bfloat, alpha: afloat)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you `init` twice?

Comment: It's a typo just remove `self.init()`.

Comment: @TimurBernikovich My point is that removal would require a _failable_ initializer...

Comment: @Alladinian yeah. You need to choose between returning default value, returning optional value and failable init. :)

Comment: @TimurBernikovich Thanks for that, I am quite aware. I still try to point out politely that the answer is wrong :P

Comment: You don't need to call twice, but when you add guard's you need to return something, `fatalError` see my update code.

Comment: @SagiShmuel ...or make the initializer failable and return nil (which is my original point)

Comment: @Alladinian You can't return nil, only if you set the init as optional, like that: `convenience init?(fromString: String)`

Answer (score 2):

So, basically you have 3 options.

1. Return optional value.

```swift
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(commaSeparatedComponents: String) {
        let components = commaSeparatedComponents
            .split(separator: ",")
            .compactMap { Double(String($0)) }
            .map { CGFloat($0) }
        guard components.count == 4 else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(
            red: components[0],
            green: components[1],
            blue: components[2],
            alpha: components[3]
        )
    }
}
```

2. Return default value.

```swift
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(commaSeparatedComponents: String) {
        let components = commaSeparatedComponents
            .split(separator: ",")
            .compactMap { Double(String($0)) }
            .map { CGFloat($0) }
        if components.count != 4 {
            self.init()
        } else {
            self.init(
                red: components[0],
                green: components[1],
                blue: components[2],
                alpha: components[3]
            )
        }
    }
}
```

3. Throw errors.

```swift
extension String: Error { }
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(commaSeparatedComponents: String) throws {
        let components = commaSeparatedComponents
            .split(separator: ",")
            .compactMap { Double(String($0)) }
            .map { CGFloat($0) }
        guard components.count == 4 else {
            throw "Can't parse component"
        }
        self.init(
            red: components[0],
            green: components[1],
            blue: components[2],
            alpha: components[3]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Method 3: Thrown expression type 'String' does not conform to 'Error'. Method 2 working, thanks! If you fix method 3 I'll change this to the accepted

Comment: @MatthewMitchell just add `extension String: Error { }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are pretty sure about your string's format and that it **will contain RGBA values every time**, here's an alternative approach:

```
func returnColorFromString(yourRGBAString: String) -> UIColor?{
    let colorsArray = yourRGBAString.components(separatedBy: ",")
    if(colorsArray.count == 4){ // Check if it contains all the expected values
      let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
      if let redValue = numberFormatter.number(from: colorsArray[0]), let greenValue = numberFormatter.number(from: colorsArray[1]), let blueValue = numberFormatter.number(from: colorsArray[2]), let alphaValue = numberFormatter.number(from: colorsArray[3]) {
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(truncating: redValue), green: CGFloat(truncating: greenValue), blue: CGFloat(truncating: blueValue), alpha: CGFloat(truncating: alphaValue))
      }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Have tested the function and it works fine for me...

Comment: I'd recommend validating `colorsArray.count` at least.

Comment: `Formatter` creation takes a lot of time, better reuse them as much as possible